# When range partitioning, should I drop primary UUID-like key?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, partitioning

I'm aware of the limitation "every unique key on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression". So given that my primary key is a UUID, it's going to require  a change.

**Background**: I have a transaction history table that grows at about 1.5G per month (more so than I can keep upgrading server memory). The table has a PRIMARY key (uuid_short) and a datetime column, among others. There are two types of queries hitting the table: those that return a list of transactions in a date-range, and those that refer to a specific transaction through its primary key.

**Question**: Since vast majority of queries don't care for transactions more than 18 months old I thought datetime could be a candidate for range partitioning. Does this mean I'm better off dropping the PRIMARY key and converting it to a non-unique key? (dups are not a problem, the app servers guarantee there cannot be any).

The system is currently a hybrid of OLTP and OLAP scenarios which is probably why it doesn't scale.

Is partitioning going to make a positive impact on memory footprint?

If not, then I may be better off reorganizing the system by moving historical transactions to a data warehouse like AWS Redshift. It would be quite a refactoring effort, but if that's the preferred solution then I'd like to plan early.

This is MySQL 5.6.

Comment: You probably don't need to partition. Are you having performance problems that we can help with? If so, properly elaborate

Comment: @Phil: no huge performance problems yet, but I'm trying to be proactive. Reports are increasing in duration (from milliseconds ~3 yrs ago to 7-10 seconds these days), memory footprint is going up, etc. I'd like to know if there is a way to scale out, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

- Some queries involve a date range, usually "recent" dates,
- Other queries are point-queries, which involves a unique key
- You can purge data older than 18 months.

Anything else?

`UUIDs` are *terrible* for performance when the dataset size becomes too big to cache.

It would take some work, but this is what I recommend:

```
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT -- or `BIGINT` if might go past 4 billion
dt DATETIME NOT NULL  -- or TIMESTAMP if you prefer
PRIMARY KEY(dt, id)
INDEX(id)
```

Characteristics:

- The data is in datetime order, thereby making those queries very efficient,
- Tacking `id` onto the PK assures that the it is unique,
- `id` replaces your uuid_short in the application (so, code change),
- There is a PK, which InnoDB really likes to have,
- You won't need to keep adding RAM -- most of the activity is near the "end" of the table,
- `INSERTs` are very efficient -- both the data (& PK) and the secondary key (id) are being added to at the end.

Now, I will add on the purging.

`PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(dt))` is the optimal way to do it.  Define the ranges as months.  Each month: `DROP` (instantly) the oldest month and `ADD` a new month.  See [*my blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) for more details.

How to transition from uuid_short to id?

1. Add the AUTO_INCREMENT id and `INDEX(id)` to the existing table in a single `ALTER`,
2. Convert the app's use of uuid_short to `id`,
3. Drop the uuid_short column and change the indexes (all in a single `ALTER`),
4. Add `PARTITIONing`.

Steps 1,3,4 will each require copying over the entire table; the sooner you do it, the less downtime you will suffer.  Or consider `pt-online-schema-change` or `gh-ost` for doing them "online".

Another tip:  See if you can shrink any of the datatypes of other columns.